# IBM BPM sharing authentication with web application

Tags: websphere, ibm-bpm

I have java web application deployed in same IBM BPM websphere.when user open bpm screen I provide a link to the web application .
I want only the user who logged in BPM should able to access the link  but not others How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is in the same WebSphere cell, the SSO between apps is enabled by default. Check this page [Single sign-on for authentication using LTPA cookies](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7K4U_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/csec_sso.html), your second application just have to have security constraints defined (role, resources) and mapped to specific group of users or `all authenticated`.
If  other app is in different WebSphere cell you would need to import there LTPA key from your BPM cell. Also see other constraints from the link above.